# jquery audio player control panel - add class to last value in var array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, var

Whenever I play multiple tracks and then hit the red stop button on the master control and then hit the green play, it will add the pause class (spin.gif) to every black play that has been clicked before. (You will notice it if you play and stop more than one song with red button.)

I believe every time I play a new track it is adding it into an array for var nowplay. I want it so when I press the green play button it only adds pause class (spin.gif) to the last played aka nowplay.pop()

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jeffd/5p86Lk9d/5/

```
$(".play").on('click', function () {
     var key = $(this).attr('key');
     var nowplay = $(this); // variable for now playing class .play

    EvalSound(this, key);
     $(".play").not(this).removeClass("pause");     
     $(this).toggleClass("pause");
     $(this).hasClass("pause") ? $(".playerbottom").addClass("pausebottom") : $(".playerbottom").removeClass("pausebottom");

    $(".playerbottom").on('click', function () {

     $(this).hasClass("pausebottom") ? nowplay.addClass("pause") : nowplay.removeClass("pause");

 }); 

});
 var thissound = new Audio();
 var currentKey;
 function EvalSound(el, key) {
     thissound.addEventListener('ended', function () {
         // done playing
         $(el).removeClass("pause");
         $(".playerbottom").removeClass("pausebottom");
     });
     if (currentKey !== key) thissound.src = "http://99centbeats.com/1e4cb5f584d055a0992385c1b2155786/" + key;
     currentKey = key;
     if (thissound.paused) thissound.play();
     else thissound.pause();
     currentPlayer = thissound;
 }

$(".volume_slider").slider({
    value  : 75,
    step   : 1,
    range  : 'min',
    min    : 0,
    max    : 100,
    slide  : function(){
        var value = $(".volume_slider").slider("value");
        thissound.volume = (value / 100);
    }
}); 
 $(".playerbottom").on('click', function () {
     $(this).toggleClass("pausebottom");
     if (thissound.paused) thissound.play();
     else thissound.pause();

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

After making nowplay a global variable it works! window.nowplay = $(this);

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jeffd/2gbz7agp/

```
$(".play").on('click', function () {
         var key = $(this).attr('key');
         window.nowplay = $(this); // variable for now playing class .play
         EvalSound(this, key);
         $(".play").not(this).removeClass("pause");     
         $(this).toggleClass("pause");
         $(this).hasClass("pause") ? $(".playerbottom").addClass("pausebottom") : $(".playerbottom").removeClass("pausebottom");
     $(".playerbottom").on('click', function () {
          $(this).hasClass("pausebottom") ? nowplay.addClass("pause") : nowplay.removeClass("pause");

     }); 

    });
     var thissound = new Audio();
     var currentKey;
     function EvalSound(el, key) {
         thissound.addEventListener('ended', function () {
             // done playing
             $(el).removeClass("pause");
             $(".playerbottom").removeClass("pausebottom");
         });
         if (currentKey !== key) thissound.src = "http://99centbeats.com/1e4cb5f584d055a0992385c1b2155786/" + key;
         currentKey = key;
         if (thissound.paused) thissound.play();
         else thissound.pause();
         currentPlayer = thissound;
     }

    $(".volume_slider").slider({
        value  : 75,
        step   : 1,
        range  : 'min',
        min    : 0,
        max    : 100,
        slide  : function(){
            var value = $(".volume_slider").slider("value");
            thissound.volume = (value / 100);
        }
    }); 
     $(".playerbottom").on('click', function () {
         $(this).toggleClass("pausebottom");
         if (thissound.paused) thissound.play();
         else thissound.pause();

     });
```